# Conflict between global functions and argument functions Maxima

Tags: function, scope, arguments, maxima, polynomials

Working with polynomials in Maxima, I'm making a function to obtain from a polynomial another with the same roots, but all of them simple.

```
simplify(p):=block(
  local(q,d,c),
  define(q(x),diff(p(x),x)),
  define(d(x),gcd(p(x),q(x))),
  define(c(x),divide(p(x),d(x))[1]),

  return(c(x))
);
```

When I use the function with a polynomial `s` and no `p` is defined outside, everything works fine:

```
(%i1)   s(x):=x^2-1;
        simplify(s);

(%o1)   s(x):=x^2-1
(%o2)   x^2-1
```

However, after defining a polynomial `p` everything changes:

```
(%i3)   p(x):=x^6-5*x^5-10*x^4+86*x^3-99*x^2-81*x+108;

(%o3)   p(x):=x^6-5x^5+(-10)*x^4+86*x^3+(-99)*x^2+(-81)*x+108

(%i4)   simplify(p);
(%o4)   x^4+x^3-13x^2-x+12

(%i5)   simplify(s);
(%o5)   x^4+x^3-13x^2-x+12
```

The problem, I think, is due to that Maxima is taking `p` as the global function, once it is defined, and then it no longer considers the function `s` given as argument.

Is there a way to indicate inside the function that we want to use the argument function `p` instead of the global function? I haven't found any alternative to distinguish between both functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the global definition of `p` supersedes any other. Maxima has some confused ideas about scope and this is one of them; I consider it a serious problem.

Anyway to work around it you can declare `p` to be local in the function in which is an argument. I think you can just put `p` in the `local` declaration in `simplify`.